# IllegalStateExceptioncom.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandler in prepare

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm facing some random crash in production on Android.
Here is the logcat give me that:

```
2019-11-20 15:00:09.752 3248-3248/? E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2019-11-20 15:00:09.752 3248-3248/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-11-20 15:00:09.774 3248-3248/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already prepared or hasn't been reset
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandler.prepare(GestureHandler.java:178)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.recordHandlerIfNotPresent(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:379)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.recordViewHandlersForPointer(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:389)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:466)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:403)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.onTouchEvent(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:97)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootHelper.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerRootHelper.java:121)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootView.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerRootView.java:36)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView.java:39)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dis
2019-11-20 15:00:09.776 3248-3248/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-11-20 15:00:09.783 3248-3248/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.evolum, PID: 3248
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already prepared or hasn't been reset
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandler.prepare(GestureHandler.java:178)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.recordHandlerIfNotPresent(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:379)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.recordViewHandlersForPointer(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:389)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:466)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:422)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.traverseWithPointerEvents(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:464)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.extractGestureHandlers(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:403)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.GestureHandlerOrchestrator.onTouchEvent(GestureHandlerOrchestrator.java:97)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootHelper.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerRootHelper.java:121)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootView.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerRootView.java:36)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView.dispatchTouchEvent(RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView.java:39)
2019-11-20 15:00:09.785 3248-3248/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry, StatusBar, YellowBox } from 'react-native';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import App from './src/App';

StatusBar.setHidden(true);
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['-[RCTRootView cancelTouches]` is deprecated and will be deleted soon.']);
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
...
export default gestureHandlerRootHOC(App);
```

My environment:
react: 16.9.0
react-native:  0.61.4
react-native-gesture-handler:  ^1.5.0

JS error:

[image]

If someone can help me to avoid this crash and the error message when I reload that can be really nice.

thanks,
Youcef

Comment: I found a temporary solution: https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/841#issuecomment-559498002